# Flex space-between: ghost space

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a strange issue with flexbox and chrome since today, this code was working last friday.

I have a "ghost space" (looks like a margin) under my link. And always when I check it in Chrome Dev Tools, their computed margins and paddings are always zeroed (as expected). (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrNJS.jpg)

Here is a codepen : http://codepen.io/AlexandreJolly/pen/ygqREb

Haml:

```
.card
    .card-top
        %h3 Test
        %p Lorem
    .card-bottom
        %a{:href => "#"} Link
```

Sass:

```
.card
    background: white
    width: 100%
    height: auto
    min-height: 192px
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: space-between

.card-top
    background-color: green

.card-bottom
    background-color: red
```

I've tested this code in Firefox Dev Edition, Vivaldi and Firefox and it seems working. It doesn't work in Chrome and Opera.

I think it an issue with a Chrome/webkit update this weekend or am I missing something?

Comment: What is meant to happen? should the red be flush against the bottom (minus the padding)

Comment: @Pete Yes. Here is what is meant to happen : http://imgur.com/53b08Kx

Comment: works for me, looks like your imate,  chrome on mac

Comment: How's this: https://jsfiddle.net/p7a1sw2j/2/

Comment: @Dejan.S I checked on a MS windows desktop and it works. I'm actually on Chrome 56 for MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Remove 
line-height: 2rem;
and
line-height: 1.15;
from "normalize.css"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with ghost space when stacking two elements using `flex-flow:column` then setting one of the elements height to 0. Setting the max-height to some value in my case 100% solved the issue for me.